# Transparent textures being handled oddly

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL why is it that when rendering transparent textures it changes the color values of all the pixels? Ex. when [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vandench/LWJGL-Stuff/master/src/main/resources/assets/textures/Cube.png) transparent texture is rendered it comes out as [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vandench/LWJGL-Stuff/master/bugs/cube.png%20-%20error.png). Also if I change the texture to not have transparency it still has the same problem of changing pixel values. What causes OpenGL to completely change a transparent texture when it is rendered? (Note: the textures have been created in GIMP and the program is running on a mac (OSX 10.10.3))

**EDIT**:

Turns out this happens when you load a texture with transparency on the RGB color spectrum instead of the RGBA spectrum.